# PHP date_parse from unix timestamp

Tags: php, date, datetime, unix, timestamp

So I have the date `07.May.2008 20:43` in unix timestamp (`1210193026`)

According to PHP's manual's [page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) for **date_parse()** the function accepts

> Date in format accepted by strtotime().

and according to **strtotime()**'s [page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) it accepts

> A date/time string. Valid formats are explained in Date and Time
>   Formats.

So the Compound Dates' [page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) says it accepts unix timestamps in the format of

> **"@" "-"? [0-9]+**

And of course the following code works:

```
echo strtotime('@1210193026');
```

and produces `1210193026` which is fine and is what it should be.

But the following one

```
$date = date_parse('@1210193026');
var_dump($date);
```

prints out

```
array(16) {
  ["year"]=>
  int(1970)
  ["month"]=>
  int(1)
  ["day"]=>
  int(1)
  ["hour"]=>
  int(0)
  ["minute"]=>
  int(0)
  ["second"]=>
  int(0)
  ["fraction"]=>
  float(0)
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["is_localtime"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["zone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["zone"]=>
  int(0)
  ["is_dst"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["relative"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["year"]=>
    int(0)
    ["month"]=>
    int(0)
    ["day"]=>
    int(0)
    ["hour"]=>
    int(0)
    ["minute"]=>
    int(0)
    ["second"]=>
    int(1210193026)
  }
}
```

I've tested on two different machines

**PHP 7.0.0RC7 (cli) (built: Nov 11 2015 12:16:11) ( NTS )** (Windows 10)

and

**PHP 5.6.16 (cli) (built: Dec  4 2015 12:50:33)** (Cent OS 7)

Question is what can I use to parse a unix timestamp to a date array and the second, less important, question is why is **date_parse()** not working in the way it is expected.

Comment: `$date = date_parse(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1210193026));`

Comment: As to why, perhaps you've actually found a bug in PHP

Comment: isn't this clumsy? converting one way and then the other? Wouldn't wanna waste cpu power for no reason.

Comment: What's wrong with `date_parse('07.May.2008 20:43')`?

Comment: Or `$date = new DateTime('@1210193026');`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver nothing is wrong with it. It's just i have it in a timestamp format passed from somewhere else.

Comment: @Machavity I prefer not to use a Date Object when it's possible.

Comment: ANy particular reason why you want to avoid DateTime objects, they have some very real advantages over unix timestamps, like being daylight savings aware, timezone aware, etc

Comment: @MarkBaker it's not really what i need. I need an array of the date and time elements and while i can further process it and again pass it to date_parse, why would i need that? wouldn't it be a waste of memory and processing power? Probably not that significant but it's part of a framework code that affects multiple projects.

Comment: Well you can get all the information from a DateTime object that date_parse provides